# overlaypanel primefaces doesnt work fine inside dialog inside tabview

Tags: primefaces, overlay, panel

I use the dynamic overlayPanel of primefaces inside one `p:tab` inside one `p:dialog` like this  :

```
    <p:dialog id="dialog" modal="true" header="Nouveau Article"
            widgetVar="dlg">

            <h:form prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <p:tabView id="monpanel">  

                    <p:tab id="tab1" title="Informations">
                    ....
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab id="tab2" title="Prix">
                    ....
                    </p:tab>
     <p:tab id="tab3" title="Stock et fournisseurs">


                        <h:outputLabel value="" /><h:outputLabel value="" /><h:outputLabel value="" />

                        <p:commandButton id="carBtn" value="Selectionner Fournisseurs" type="button" />

                        <p:overlayPanel  appendToBody="true" my="left top" id="carPanel" for="carBtn" hideEffect="fade"
                            dynamic="true">
                            <p:dataTable id="table" var="car" rowKey="#{car.fournisseurId}" 
                             value="#{articlesMB.listfournisseurs}"  selection="#{articlesMB.selectedFournisseurs}"
                                rows="10" paginator="true" >
                                <p:column  selectionMode="multiple" style="width:20px" />
                                <p:column headerText="Id">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.fournisseurId}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="Nom">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.personne.nom}" />
                                </p:column>

                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:overlayPanel>

                        </p:tab>
                         </p:tabView>
<p:commandButton id="article-ajouter"
                    update=":messages monpanel :articlesdata"
                    action="#{articlesMB.ajouter}" value="add" />
                         </h:form>
                         </p:dialog>
```

in the first time it works fine, but when I click on the add button and the validation failed (for any cause) and I click on dynamic button of overlaypanel, it appears but when I check or uncheck one of rows of datatable it disappear, I don't know the cause

do you have any idea how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cammandButton should use 'process' attribute, you specify component to submit info(not specify overlay).

For ex:

```
<p:inputText id="txttest" required="true" value="" />
<p:commandButton process="txttest" id="article-ajouter"
                    update=":messages monpanel :articlesdata"
                    action="#{articlesMB.ajouter}" value="add" />
```

Comment: while I have a lot of components to process (only one or two don't be process), then can I except it rather than process the rest

Comment: you can, for ex: process="@(:input:not(select))" (Process input components but not select components)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your overlay panel only works once is because you update the panel that holds the command button that `overlayPanel` is attached to. 
It is a bug in `overlayPanel` emerged after PF 5. You can fix this without resorting process attribute, I think solutions like this reduces the readability of the code.

If you define a `widgetVar` to `overlayPanel`, say `'carPanelWDG'`, and call `PF('carPanelWDG').loadContents()` function in the `onComplete` event of the command button everything just works. And even if there is no comment explaining the reason why you did such a thing, anyone can interpret this easily.